# Unity C# error: (12,47): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>' to 'float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist, syntax-error, gameobject

I'm new to programming in general.

With another Script i store in the list "spawnPointC" all gameobjects called spawnPointC that appear from spawning other prefabs.

I want to pick a random GameObject from that list, and store it's position to spawn another object at the same position later.

I've tried some other things, but i don't know what i'm doing.

How would you do it?

```
1  using System.Collections;
2  using System.Collections.Generic;
3  using UnityEngine;
4
5  public class CspList : MonoBehaviour
6  {
7    public List<GameObject> spawnPointsC;
8    [SerializeField] private GameObject goal;
9 
10   void Start()
11   {
12       GameObject spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC);
13 
14      float pointX = spawnIndex.transform.position.x;
15      float pointY = spawnIndex.transform.position.y;
16      float pointZ = spawnIndex.transform.position.z;
17
18      Vector3 pointSpawn = new Vector3(pointX, pointY, pointZ);
19      Instantiate(goal, pointSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
20   }
21 }
```

Comment: Well you probably rather wanted `GameObject spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC.Count);` ... a `List<XY>` is not an `int` or `float` ^^ I would categorize this as a typo ;)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i tried that and the error i get with that is:

Comment: (12,31): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: show us your edited code

Comment: oh i know. Now you tried to use integer as a game object here: `float pointX = spawnIndex.transform.position.x;`

Comment: How do i show a screenshot in the comments? Ahm, is that right, Szpur?

Comment: I edited my original post down below and added proper solution, at least in my opinion :D

Comment: oh sorry ^^ copy paste mistake: `int spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC.Count);` ... a `GameObject` is not an index either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as said you simply wanted to pass in

```
spawnPointsC.Count
```

since you want the amount of items, not the entire list instance.

Further for an index it makes no sense to have the type `GameObject`. You want an `int` or simply `var` since the compiler already "knows" what is returned by `Random.Range` anyway, there is no need to explicitly tell it that it is an `int`

```
var spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC.Count);
```

---

And as a side note a `Vector3` is a struct. You can shorten your code to simply

```
void Start()
{
    // this is an int!
    var spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC.Count);
    //                          this returns the according GameObject item from the list
    //                          | 
    //                          |                   Now you access the Transform and it's position only ONCE
    //                          |                   |
    //                          v                   v
    var randomSpawnPoint = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex].transform.position;
      
    // Since Vector3 is a struct it is a COPY by VALUE
    // There is no need for using new, just pass it on
    Instantiate(goal, randomSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

this is also way more efficient than repeatedly accessing the array and/or properties of the object

Comment: I literally copy-pasted and can now run the code, only get this error:  ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: if that so, maybe your list is empty?

Comment: I was thinking that i might have to delay this script as the list is created when i start the game, (because of spawning prefabs at Start). So the list is empty in the Start.

Comment: hmm after the Delay i still get the error, and the list isn't empty anymore.

Comment: I GOT IT, both codes you provided as solution are correct, i wasn't referencing the List correctly in the second code (as i separated them due to the delay) but that wasn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

The errors tells you that you trying to list of GameObjects as float and its happening here:

`GameObject spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC.Count);`

I'm not exactly sure why you would try to do, but maybe try to use spawnPointsC.Count as @derHugo mention.

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CspList : MonoBehaviour
{
   public List<GameObject> spawnPointsC;
   [SerializeField] private GameObject goal;

   void Start()
   {
      int spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPointsC.Count);
     
      float pointX = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex].transform.position.x;
      float pointY = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex].transform.position.y;
      float pointZ = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex].transform.position.z;
     
      Vector3 pointSpawn = new Vector3(pointX, pointY, pointZ);
      Instantiate(goal, pointSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
  }
}
```

Comment: So i tried this:```                                                                                                                    
      float pointX = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex -1].transform.position.x;
      float pointY = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex -1].transform.position.y;
      float pointZ = spawnPointsC[spawnIndex -1].transform.position.z;                      ```                                                                                                         (16,35): error CS0019: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'GameObject' and 'int'

Comment: fixed again, refresh comment :D

Comment: @LSXY fix erros one by one from top to bottom

Comment: @Szpur your comment on `-1` is wrong though .. the upper bound of `Random.Range(int,int)` is **exclusive** .. it would even produce an error now if the random happens to return `0` you try to access index `-1` ;)

Comment: thats happed when you try to help too harshly XD

Comment: ok, so i see you changed the data type of GameObject to int, i really think i need it as a GameObject, i will try some other things you said too, brb.

Comment: also i changed lines 14,15,16 -> use list with index you generated